# EDI Tradacoms message format tables

Tags: edi, tradacoms

Various EDI definition documents have tables with the following headers:

SEGMENT, DATA ELEMENT, M/C, F/V, PICTURE, REMARKS

I have two questions:
1. PICTURE appears to define the required format, is the term picture a reference to a specific formatting language type?

2.What does F/V stand for?

See the following for examples of this data table:

http://doczz.net/doc/4490138/tradacoms-definition-for-edi-issues-version-4

http://www.hofsuppliers.co.uk/info/pdf/bulk_invoice_tradacoms.pdf

Comment: hi andrew, PICTURE = format. like an..35 in edifact.  TRADACOMS uses their own terminology. V=value, F=fixed, lke for qualifiers and codes.

Comment: better to use official TRADACOMS docs next to hof's documentation.